# Как передать информацию об использовании приложения?

Tags: сервер, веб-служба, сервисы

Есть у меня куча инфы об использовании моего приложения, логи, настройки, использование хоткеев итд. То-есть приложение иногда должно отсылать данные на сервер. Какие есть сервисы для сбора такой инфы?

Теоретически можно на пастебин заливать, но как потом найти нужное на пастебин?

Могу поднять свой сервер, но он не может быть 24/7. Можно арендовать сервер и домен, но это недешевое удовольствие.

Может есть какой-то сервис у гугла или что-то на подобии grafana?

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на решения от FireBase (https://firebase.google.com/?hl=en) . Можете использовать облачную базу данных куда будете публиковать данные с клиентов.

У них есть бесплатный план для не сильно крупных приложений.